# Amazon Redshift: How to associate `stl_load_errors` row with the correct table name when the found table id doesn't match?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

### Problem summary

I use a COPY query to load data from S3 to a Redshift table `t1`.

99% of the time there's no errors, data is correctly loaded. So I know there's no mistake on the loaded table name.

But when there are errors, depending on the table I loaded, I can't always correctly track which error happened during loading of this specific table because, for some loaded tables like `t1`, the table identifier `tbl` found in `stl_load_errors` doesn't correspond to the one expected for table `t1`.

I filter `stl_load_errors` both on `filename` and `tbl`, because a same S3 file may be loaded to different tables, so filtering on filename only isn't a safe way to check if there were errors during one specific COPY query.

### Details

The loaded table name doesn't appear in this table, instead, we get an integer identifier `1234567` in the column `tbl`. We have to join with another table `stv_tbl_perm` that contains both name and identifier, to get the name. This "trick" is shown in the Redshift documentation.

For some tables, like `t1`, the error row I may found in `stl_load_errors` after using `COPY t1 ...` will have an identifier `1234567` in `tbl` column that doesn't correspond to anything found in `stv_tbl_perm`. As if it was the identifier of a temporary table.

Then, when I look in `stv_tbl_perm` for`"name"='t1'`, I do find an identifier `10111213` in column `id`, but it's not the one I saw in `stl_load_errors`.

What makes it even more confusing is that my method of filtering errors on file and table, works perfectly fine for some Redshift tables, the `id` found is the one expected, it matches with the correct `name` in `stv_tbl_perm`.

Why would my COPY to a table go through what seems like a temporary table for some table, and not for others?

### Reproduction

I tried to simplify my process as much as possible for sharing and managed to reproduce my issue as follows.

**1. Create table, insert rows so it's not empty and check it.**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.t1
(
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(36),
    price NUMERIC(6,2)
);
insert into t1 VALUES (1, 'paul', 10.50);
select * from t1;
```

**2. Create an S3 file with a deliberate type error**

I write a character in the column "id" so it will cause a type error during loading.

```sql
unload ('select ''a'' as "id", ''pierre'' as "name", 2.50 as "price"')   
to 's3://my-bucket/redshift-load-error-table-id/unload/t1_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/my-user'
parallel off 
delimiter ',';
```

Make sure to replace `my-bucket`, `1111111111` and `my-user` with your own values.

**3. Load this file into the table using COPY**

```sql
COPY t1
from 's3://my-bucket/redshift-load-error-table-id/unload/t1_000'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/my-user'
CSV;
```

Query fails as expected, generating a row in table `stl_load_errors`.

**4. Check for the table id in the new error row in `stl_load_errors`**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM stl_load_errors 
where trim(filename) = 's3://my-bucket/redshift-load-error-table-id/unload/t1_000';
```

We find the row corresponding to the file and keep the table identifier found in the column `tbl`, let's say `"tbl" = 1234567` (you'll get something different).

**5. Look up this table identifier in `stv_tbl_perm` to get the table name**

```sql
select *
from stv_tbl_perm 
where id='1234567';
```

This returns nothing, the identifier found doesn't correspond to any permanent table listed in `stv_tbl_perm`.
As if it was the identifier of a temporary table.

**6. Look up the expected identifier of the table we loaded to**

```sql
select *
from stv_tbl_perm 
where name='t1';
```

This returns `10111213` (you'll get something different), and this is the identifier I should have gotten in the `tbl` column of table `stl_load_errors`.

If I try another COPY with an error, another line will appear in the error table, with again another identifier different from both previous identifier. This also indicates it could be the identifier of a temporary table.

### Consequence

I therefore cannot filter `stl_load_errors` for the specific table I applied the COPY query on.

Surprisingly, this process works perfectly fine for some of my tables and I can't find any difference in the way I do it between the tables for which it works and the tables for which it doesn't.

I haven't found any reference to that issue on the web yet. It requires a lot of details so it's hard to search too.

Any idea?

Comment: I have posted my issue on the AWS Developer forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=301324).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was identified as an actual Redshift issue due to a recent Redshift feature by an AWS engineer on the AWS developer forum where I posted my problem.

@joeharris76-AWS:

> OK, thank you for bringing this to our attention. We've identified the
>   source of this issue and will investigate a fix. When it is fixed a
>   note will to appear in our regular maintenance announcements at the
>   top of the forum.
>
> This is related to the automatic DISTSTYLE feature we introduced
>   recently. For DISTSTYLE AUTO tables that are currently ALL, we load
>   new data into a temp table and then check if the new rows added
>   require the table to be converted from ALL to EVEN.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html
>
> > DISTSTYLE { AUTO | EVEN | KEY | ALL }   The default is AUTO. …   AUTO:
> >     Amazon Redshift assigns an optimal distribution style based on the
> >     table data. For example, if AUTO distribution style is specified,
> >     Amazon Redshift initially assigns ALL distribution to a small table,
> >     then changes the table to EVEN distribution when the table grows
> >     larger. The change in distribution occurs in the background, in a few
> >     seconds. …
>
> There are 2 ways work around this:
>
> 1. Define an explicit DISTSTYLE of EVEN, KEY, or ALL on the table being loaded. I recommend this option primarily for tables that can
>      use a KEY diststyle. If you are not using KEY then the AUTO diststyle
>      will be the most efficient.
> 2. Retrieve the query ID from the stl_load_errors, retrieve the SQL from stl_querytext for the query, and then look up the table by name
>      from pg_class, svv_table_info, or stv_tbl_perm.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897976

Specifying a `DISTSTYLE` in my little reproduction does solve the problem and I'll apply the same solution to my production tables because they seem to fit with the EVEN style (hundreds of millions of rows, no joins).

So in my reproduction case, I add a line in the table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.t1
(
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(36),
    price NUMERIC(6,2)
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN;
```

And now the table identifier found in `stl_load_errors` does correspond to the expected table in `stv_tbl_perm`.

I have also tested the method with the querying of the `stl_querytext` table, and it works too in my reproduction case, but I don't find it very clean nor effective to parse a string to find the table name inside, so I'll stick with adding `DISTSTYLE EVEN` in my current cases.

Comment: Please note that we strongly recommend using the AUTO diststyle or the KEY diststyle if you can. These styles will provide the best performance in most cases. EVEN should be used as a fallback when you do not have a good key for distributing the data or the obvious key is very skewed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `stv_tbl_perm` use `pg_class`. You can use the `oid` (database object id) columns in the Postgres catalog tables as joining columns

```
select c.relname table_name, s.* 
  from stl_load_errors s, pg_class c 
 where c.oid = s.tbl
   and c.relname = '<your table name>'
```

For more info

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG.html

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: This returns the same id as `stv_tbl_perm` for the same table name. So similarly, it doesn't correspond to the id found in `stl_load_errors`.

Comment: I replicated your case on my Redshift cluster. The first column in the SQL will give you the table name. `stl_load_error` will still have the id

Comment: Your SQL query returns the table name as first column **if** the value of `tbl` found in  `stl_load_error` corresponds to a value of `oid` in `pg_class`. And that's precisely not the case, for some tables, in the behavior I'm describing, that's the core of the problem. Seems like my reproduction case didn't cause any problem for you, it also works for me for some tables, but not for others.

Comment: Got it. Sorry I couldn't help more. Maybe you can try AWS support

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying. :)
I will try with AWS forum tomorrow to respect the unwritten rule that you should wait before double posting for help in different websites! I'll link it under my question.